# Putting static functions in a Haxe typedef

Tags: haxe

In the programming language Haxe, I have multiple different 'item' classes that should be able to give a value when provided with some arguments. These functions should have no contact with actual object instances, but still belong in these class, thus, they should be static.

However, I want to be able to pass in the 'Apple' or 'Mango' class (not an instance) and call a static method. Normally I would create a typedef if I wanted to be able to access method, however what do I do when the method is static?
eg -

```
class food
+eat() 
+throw()

Apple extends food
+eat()
+(static) getFatLevels (p:Person)

Mango extends food
+eat()
+throw()
+(static) getFatLevels (p:Person)
```

...

```
function chooseBestFood () {
    for (food in Foods){
         if (food.getFatLevels(person) < lowest){
             return (food);
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typedefs work fine, but you need to use *class notation* to avoid "is method but should be var" errors:

```
typedef HasMagic = {
    function magic():Void;
}

class Foo {
    public static function magic()
    {
        return 314;
    }
}

class Bar {
    public static function magic()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}

class Test {
    static function main()
    {
        var items:Array<HasMagic> = [Foo, Bar];
        for (i in items)
            trace(i.magic());
    }
}
```

([on try haxe](http://try.haxe.org/#fDD48))

You might also need to [restrict DCE](http://haxe.org/manual/cr-dce.html) in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

I don't follow how you would use typedefs here. However, if you know your child classes will all implement this static method, you can do the following in a non-type-safe way:

```
class Food
{
    static function main() {
        var myFoodClass:Class<Food> = Apple;
        var method = Reflect.field(myFoodClass, "getFatLevels");
        trace(Reflect.callMethod(myFoodClass, method, []));
    }
}

class Apple extends Food
{
    public static function getFatLevels():Int
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```